# When resized, responsive navigation disappears?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive drop down navigation that has been experiencing quite a hiccup in terms of functionality.

Basically, the page will load correctly, everything will work, etc. If I resize the page to show my mobile nav, it will show my hamburger menu, let me click and close and all work. *But here is the issue*

- If I go to mobile, open it, then resize without closing it, the nav will stay visible.
- If I go to mobile, open it, then close it, then resize to full, the nav will be gone.

I included some basic HTML my JS function, as well as a link to the site in question.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="container1">
    <a class="nav-logo" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.svg"></a>
    <div class="mobile">
      <ul class="menu nav-left">
        <a href="html/main-pages/portfolio.html"><li class="button">Work</li></a>
        <a href="html/main-pages/resume.html"><li class="button">Resume</li></a>
        <a href="html/main-pages/contact.php"><li class="button">Contact</li></a>
      </ul>

      <ul class="menu nav-right">
        <a href="#"><li class="button"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li class="button"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li class="button"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li class="button"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li class="button"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <span class="nav-toggle"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $( document ).ready(function(){
        $(".nav-toggle").click(function(){
        $(".mobile").slideToggle(500);

        });
});
```

Last but not least, you can find the problem on **[this website](http://www.idesignradthings.com)**. Thanks for the help everyone, if there is any questions, I'll be happy to answer them.

For future reference, here is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2s8b9mft/)**

Comment: You need to add media queries to make sure that the `.mobile` element is  hidden on mobile and visible at anything above mobile. The hamburger menu toggles `display:none;` on that element when you close it.

Comment: If it toggles, wouldn't that mean clicking it again, toggles it back to block?

Comment: Yes, and it does. That's why if you have the mobile menu open before you resize you can still see it on desktop.

Comment: @APAD1 I see, I must have overlooked setting display:block on the full screen media query. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when closing the menu on mobile, `.mobile` will get a display none. This can be fixed by `!important`.

```
@media { /* your desktop media query */
  .mobile {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Figures it's something super easy that I might have overlooked... lol

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .mobile {display: block !important;}
}
```